# using python `eval()` with a method

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, datetime, for-loop

My ultimate goal is to get the day, month and year of two days, today and yesterday in a nested `for` loop.

Below I am importing stuff and defining `today` and `yesterday`

```
import datetime as dt
from datetime import timedelta 
today = dt.date.today()
yesterday = today - timedelta(1)
```

Now I am defining a dictionary to map the format of each year, month and day

```
d_day_format = {'year': '%y',
                'month': '%m',
                'day': '%d'}
```

So now I want to create the following variables: `today_year` (20), `today_month` (12), `today_day` (31), `yesterday_year` (20), `yesterday_month` (12) and `yesterday_day` (30)

I am using `eval()` to get the values of the variables from strings, as shown in the loop below

```
for d in 'today yesterday'.split():
    for k in d_day_format.keys():
        globals()[f"{d}_{k}"] = eval(d).eval(k).format(f"{d_day_format[k]}")
```

the first part of the variable assignment `eval(d)` works, though it appears I cannot use `eval()` for methods:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~/installed/python/demuxDelayer/demuxDelayer_v2.py in <module>
      1 for d in 'today yesterday'.split():
      2     for k in d_day_format.keys():
----> 3         globals()[f"{d}_{k}"] = eval(d).eval(k).format(f"{d_day_format[k]}")

AttributeError: 'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'eval'
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: You'd want to use `getattr` instead of `eval` on the object returned by the first `eval` call. You don't even need the first `eval` call either though. You're basically using `eval` to do a dictionary lookup, which is overkill for the task. Put the objects in a dictionary instead of using loose variables, then just do a typical lookup.

Answer (score 0):

Python’s eval() allows you to evaluate arbitrary Python expressions from a string-based or compiled-code-based input. This function can be handy when you’re trying to dynamically evaluate Python expressions from any input that comes as a string or a compiled code object.  In this case, you are overly complicating the problem.  This is how I would accomplish what you want.

```
import datetime as dt
from datetime import timedelta 
today = dt.date.today()
yesterday = today + timedelta(days=-1)  #Note changed from your original
cntl_dict={'year':'year%100', 'month':'month', 'day':'day'}
inrecord = {'today':today, 'yesterday':yesterday}
for k, v in inrecord.items():
    for l, w in cntl_dict.items():
        print(f'{k}-{l}: {eval(f"{k}.{w}")}')
```

Yields:

```
today_year': 20
today_month': 12
today_day': 31
yesterday_year': 20
yesterday_month': 12
yesterday_day': 30
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, though I am trying to build the output iteratively i.e. in a loop, and not with manual key value assignment

Comment: Can you elaborate further on what you are trying to do?  It is unclear from your description what you mean by without manual key value assignment.

Comment: I just updated my answer to build the output iteratively.